# How to select all elements beside all childs where a parent has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to select **all elements which are not inside of the print class**. And I want an selection which really selects every element by it's one. (no inheritance). How can I do this? Javascript is fine as well.

So **3, 4, 5** shouldn't be red.

```css
body *:not(.print) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!--this one-->
  1
  <!--this one-->
  <p>2</p>
  <!--this one-->
</div>
<div>
  <div class="print">
    3
    <p>4</p>
    <div>
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <!--this one-->
  6
  <p>7</p>
  <!--this one-->
</div>
```

Comment: `body *:not(.print):not(.print *)` maybe?

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, works! Thank you :) However I did a mistake in my example: My original is inside a div: There your solution isn't working.. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Select all in body and add this rule: `.print, .print * {color: black;}`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED:

Try this:

```
html {
   color: red;
}

.print, .print * {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. It's also not working with the update example (when the class is inside a div without print) ..

Comment: Also, it seems @Teemu posted a very similar response before I did.

Comment: Yes, it's quite similar. Adding `*` to the root selector might select the elements more like OP seems to need. [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) is a bit problematic because it's not standardized yet, and its behavior may vary depending on the used browser.